# Pandas: applying function to dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe

```
weight       height
  56           167
  88           179
  42           159
  51           162
  90           170
```

And I try to apply some function

```
def min_error(w0, w1, height, weight):
    return np.sum(np.power((height - (w0 + w1*weight))), 2)

(data.apply(lambda row: min_error(60, 0.05, row['Height'], row['Weight']), axis=1))
```

But it returns

> ValueError: ('invalid number of arguments', u'occurred at index 1')

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your call to `np.power`. You have the parenthesis in the wrong place. Try:

```
def min_error(w0, w1, height, weight):
    return np.sum(np.power((height - (w0 + w1*weight)), 2))
```

The problem is not with Pandas, but it was identified at a Pandas index, so it appeared to be an error with `data.apply`, which it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Your math formula is incorrect.  What is happening here is that np.power expects two arguments but is only receiving 1.  Check your parenthesis.

I think this is the formula you want:

```
def min_error(w0, w1, height, weight):
    return np.sum(np.power((height - (w0 + w1*weight)),2))

(data.apply(lambda row: min_error(60, 0.05, row['height'], row['weight']), axis=1))
```

Output:

```
0    10857.6400
1    13133.1600
2     9389.6100
3     9890.3025
4    11130.2500
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help you too.

```
df['min_error']=min_error(60, 0.05, df['height'], df['weight'])
```